# is iphone capable of switch between Wifi & 3G?

Tags: iphone

this is really important for me to switch between Wifi & 3G on iphone via code .
so is there any possibility any backdoor or some way to crack. i can scan all the wifi hot spot and can drag their details but i need a background process that help me to scan 3g also and allow me to auto-switch whenever it finds wifi

Comment: no its not at the moment though if it can be  done on jailbreak iphone  then  also i want to know how Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to do this in code.
The iPhone does this automatically for you anyway. As long as you have a wifi enabled on the iphone, it will pick up the wigi signal and when it can connect will automatically switch to the wifi signal.

Hope this helps.

Let me know if it did a little. thanks

**PK**

Comment: hi pawan  i want to control this by my own native app that will run on BG even after you exit from app .thats  what i am looking for